# Java FX Modular Application, Application Not found Error (Eclipse, Java version 19.0.2)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, module

Hi I have a problem with Java App which I am creating with JavaFX.

I created my javaFX project with Eclipse. This is my current file structure: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l05So.png)

I added the JavaFX libs here:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffuj7.png)
They are both in the correct classpath, I already tried deleting the JavaFX SDK lib, but that didn't help.

My module-info.java file wasn't recognized either:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWl9w.png)

I have also added the VM arguments correctly.

I am constantly getting this error message: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4oWE.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Post text rather than images, wherever practical.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the problem. Just delete the module-info.java file and everything magically gets fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

I recommend you to learn the basics about JavaFX. Please take a look at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.

**Solution:**

Create an appropriate working base application with the needed configurations. Either to this with the Link above or use a preconfigured project from GitHub for example and alter it to your needs.

The following projects are executable out of the box. Just download the code, import the project to your IDE and run the application.

To that, the preconfigured projects contain a Task/Goal for creating a fat JAR (a JAR you can double click on and then the application starts).

**Example working JavaFX application with gradle**
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

**Example working JavaFX application with maven**
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

Comment: I was following the directions in this video to setup eclipse for my project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XJicRt_FaI&t=457s. I got an error message saying: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module HelloFX not found.
Do you know how to fix this?